# Create Activity in Fragment Class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, listactivity

I have a inner class called PinnedSectionListActivity within my Fragment inner class of my MainActivity. I would like to create an instance of this PinnedSectionActivity within my fragment class. So that when my fragment class is instantiated it will return that instance of that ListActivity that was create. Keep trying to do but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Here is my MainActivity.

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView;
import com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        //mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         * 
         * I WOULD LIKE TO CREATE THE PINNEDSECTION ACTIVITY
         * WHEN THE FRAGMENT GETS INITIALIZED. WOULD I HAVE TO CREATE
         * 
         * 
         * 
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @author randolphgordon
     *
     */
    public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

        class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements PinnedSectionListAdapter {

            private final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
                R.color.green_light, 
                R.color.orange_light,
                R.color.blue_light, 
                R.color.red_light };

            public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
                super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);

                //final int sectionsNumber = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                final int sectionsNumber = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;

                prepareSections(sectionsNumber);

                int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;

                for (int i=0; i< sectionsNumber; i++) {

                    String title = null;

                    final String []country = {
                            "Korean", "Japanese", "Chinese", "Cambodian", "Loas", "Taiwamese"
                    };


                    final String [] CATEGORY = {
                        "Language",
                        "sports",
                        "love",
                        "luxury",
                        "vacation",
                        "games",
                        "home",
                        "travel",
                        "electronics",
                        "movies",
                    };

                    switch (('A' + i)) {
                    case ('A' + 0):
                        title = country[0];
                        break;
                    case ('A' + 1):
                        title = country[1];
                        break;
                    case ('A' + 2):
                        title = country[2];
                        break;
                    case ('A' + 3):
                        title = country[3];
                        break;
                    case ('A' + 4):
                        title = country[4];
                        break;
                    case ('A' + 5):
                        title = country[5];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                    //Create a new Item class with section header and Name
                    Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, title + " " + i);
                    //Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, String.valueOf((char)('A' + i)));

                    section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                    section.listPosition = listPosition++;
                    onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
                    add(section);

                    final int itemsNumber = CATEGORY.length; 

                    //(int) Math.abs((Math.cos(2f*Math.PI/3f * sectionsNumber / (i+1f)) * 25f));

                    // For loop to iterate the exact number of itemNumber
                    for (int j = 0;j < CATEGORY.length;j++) {
                        //Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, section.text.toUpperCase(Locale.KOREA) + " - " + j);
                        Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, CATEGORY[j]);
                        item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                        item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                        add(item);
                    }

                    sectionPosition++;
                }
            }

            protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) { }
            protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) { }

            @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY );
                view.setTag("" + position);
                Item item = getItem(position);
                if (item.type == Item.SECTION) {
                    //view.setOnClickListener(PinnedSectionListActivity.this);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[item.sectionPosition % COLORS.length]));
                }
                return view;
            }

            @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return getItem(position).type;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
                return viewType == Item.SECTION;
            }

        }

        class Item {

            public static final int ITEM = 0;
            public static final int SECTION = 1;

            public final int type;
            public final String text;

            public int sectionPosition;
            public int listPosition;

            public Item(int type, String text) {
                this.type = type;
                this.text = text;
            }

            @Override public String toString() {
                return text;
            }

        }



        class FastScrollAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

            private Item[] sections;

            public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
                super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
            }

            @Override protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) {
                sections = new Item[sectionsNumber];
            }

            @Override protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) {
                sections[sectionPosition] = section;
            }

            @Override public Item[] getSections() {
                return sections;
            }

            @Override public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
                if (section >= sections.length) {
                    section = sections.length - 1;
                }
                return sections[section].listPosition;
            }

            @Override public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
                if (position >= getCount()) {
                    position = getCount() - 1;
                }
                return getItem(position).sectionPosition;
            }

        }




        private boolean hasHeaderAndFooter;
        private boolean isFastScroll;
        private boolean addPadding;
        private boolean isShadowVisible = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                isFastScroll = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFastScroll");
                addPadding = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("addPadding");
                isShadowVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isShadowVisible");
                hasHeaderAndFooter = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter");
            }
            initializeHeaderAndFooter();
            initializeAdapter();
            initializePadding();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putBoolean("isFastScroll", isFastScroll);
            outState.putBoolean("addPadding", addPadding);
            outState.putBoolean("isShadowVisible", isShadowVisible);
            outState.putBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter", hasHeaderAndFooter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
            if (item != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            menu.getItem(0).setChecked(isFastScroll);
            menu.getItem(1).setChecked(addPadding);
            menu.getItem(2).setChecked(isShadowVisible);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_fastscroll:
                    isFastScroll = !isFastScroll;
                    item.setChecked(isFastScroll);
                    initializeAdapter();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_addpadding:
                    addPadding = !addPadding;
                    item.setChecked(addPadding);
                    initializePadding();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_showShadow:
                    isShadowVisible = !isShadowVisible;
                    item.setChecked(isShadowVisible);
                    ((PinnedSectionListView)getListView()).setShadowVisible(isShadowVisible);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
                    hasHeaderAndFooter = !hasHeaderAndFooter;
                    item.setChecked(hasHeaderAndFooter);
                    initializeHeaderAndFooter();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void initializePadding() {
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int padding = addPadding ? (int) (16 * density) : 0;
            getListView().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        }

        private void initializeHeaderAndFooter() {
            setListAdapter(null);
            if (hasHeaderAndFooter) {
                ListView list = getListView();

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                TextView header1 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                header1.setText("First header");
                list.addHeaderView(header1);

                TextView header2 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                header2.setText("Second header");
                list.addHeaderView(header2);

                TextView footer = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                footer.setText("Single footer");
                list.addFooterView(footer);
            }
            initializeAdapter();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initializeAdapter() {
            getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(isFastScroll);
            if (isFastScroll) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    getListView().setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
                }
                setListAdapter(new FastScrollAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
            } else {
                setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you want to have an Activity as inner class in your Fragment?

Comment: I am new to Android development. If I make silly mistake please forgive. I that I need to define activity before I can use it.

Comment: No Problem, was just wondering why you want to do that. Anyhow, having an Activity as inner class in a Fragment doesn't make much sense to me. Because Fragments are usually for reusing the same widget on different parent Activities again.

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about launching an activity from a fragment, consider playing with explicit Intents some more
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

If you want to host a view presented by an activity inside a Fragment, you're talking heresy =] Fragments are supposed to handle Fragments of an Activity; an activity is the presenter for a function the user is performing at the time. e.g. your gmail inbox is one activity, those sliding lists of messages and mail reading windows are fragments in the activity.

Here's a rule of thumb: if you can pass from one activity to the next, you should be able to do so with minimal serialization; if you are tring to manage several ways of looking at a big user state, you are inside an activity, dealing with fragments.

Death to singletons.

gl hf!

Comment: Would it be possible to just convert this inner class to a ListFragment class by itself and call it instead...?

Comment: well, let's keep this to the MVP pattern: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe your Activity that manages some fragments can implement an interface that triggers it to  update some data model, then updates an adapter that is supporting your Fragments. I think this is the reusing Szymon is referencing, and they's right, this might be possible with just a plain old activity, but you'll have to explain your UI a bit more =]

Comment: Ah, no, they meant reusing as in you want the same looking/feeling thing in another activity--that's right, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to store an instance of an activity inside a fragment. It may quite easily lead to memory leaks - you should not store a `Context` outside itself as you will likely leak it.

Anyway, you can always get an activity that is currently associated with a fragment by calling `getActivity()` method of the `Fragment` class.

Also, do not create activities as inner classes of fragments. It's best to keep them as separate classes, each within its own file.

Comment: Would you think it would be a good idea to just try and change this ListActivity to a ListFragment instead. And would it be a smooth transition..?

Comment: You may not need to use any kind of fragments unless you plan on reusing them. Try the simplest possible solution. Your question doesn't really have enough details to answer it.